How to convert a set of tensor values to a list while keeping the format float precision
I have a 3 lists of ids (sequence[i].id_column) and when I print them, I see (I don't know for what reason) the format of the second list changes! for example 4.2 becomes 4.2e+00. I tried to add all those lists to a set (unique_values) and then convert it to a list (unique_values_tensor) to make the values inside it to be unique (unique_values-sorted). however I see unique_values_sorted has different format. Please help me how can I keep all these three lists in a list that has unique values of them (not having repeated values) and in the correct format like the values displayed for the first id_column_tensor.
        unique_values = set()
        np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
        torch.set_printoptions(precision=1)  
        for i in range(start_timestep-1, start_timestep+ timestep-1):
           if sequence[i].x.size(0) > 0:
                
                id_column_tensor = torch.tensor(sequence[i].id_column, dtype=torch.float32)

                id_column_list = [float(f"{value:.4f}") if isinstance(value, float) else value for value in sequence[i].id_column]  #id_column_tensor
                unique_values.update(id_column_tensor)
                print('id_column_tensor:',id_column_tensor)
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"The tensor at sequence[{i}].x is empty.")
        print('unique_values:',unique_values)
        # Convert unique values to a tensor to get unique sorted values
        unique_values_tensor = torch.tensor(list(unique_values))   #, dtype=torch.float32
        unique_values_sorted = torch.unique(unique_values_tensor, sorted=True)
        
        print('unique_values_sorted:', unique_values_sorted)   
    

id_column_tensor: tensor([  12.0,   13.0,   13.1,   13.2,   14.0,   14.1,   15.0,   15.1,   16.0,
          16.1,   16.2,   17.0,   17.1,   18.0,   18.1,   18.2,   19.0,   19.1,
        5001.0, 5004.0, 5008.0, 5010.0])
id_column_tensor: tensor([0.0e+00, 1.0e+00, 2.0e+00, 3.0e+00, 3.1e+00, 3.2e+00, 4.0e+00, 4.1e+00,
        4.2e+00, 5.0e+00, 5.1e+00, 6.0e+00, 6.1e+00, 6.2e+00, 7.0e+00, 7.1e+00,
        8.0e+00, 8.1e+00, 8.2e+00, 9.0e+00, 9.1e+00, 9.2e+00, 1.0e+01, 1.1e+01,
        1.1e+01, 1.1e+01, 1.2e+01, 1.2e+01, 1.3e+01, 1.3e+01, 1.4e+01, 5.0e+03,
        5.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 5.0e+03])
id_column_tensor: tensor([   5.1,    6.0,    6.1,    6.2,    7.0,    7.1,    8.0,    8.1,    8.2,
           9.0,    9.1,    9.2,   10.0,   11.0,   11.1,   11.2,   12.0,   12.1,
          13.0,   13.1,   13.2,   14.0,   14.1,   15.0,   15.1,   16.0,   16.1,
          16.2,   17.0,   17.1,   18.0,   18.1,   18.2,   19.0,   19.1, 5001.0,
        5004.0, 5006.0, 5007.0, 5008.0, 5009.0, 5010.0])
unique_values: {tensor(5001.), tensor(3.1), tensor(16.1), tensor(2.), tensor(4.1), tensor(10.), tensor(16.2), tensor(13.2), tensor(16.1), tensor(5004.), tensor(5005.), tensor(13.2), tensor(6.), tensor(19.), tensor(5009.), tensor(11.1), tensor(7.), tensor(13.1), tensor(17.), tensor(8.2), tensor(9.1), tensor(11.), tensor(18.1), tensor(5006.), tensor(14.), tensor(5008.), tensor(6.2), tensor(19.1), tensor(18.), tensor(14.), tensor(11.2), tensor(7.), tensor(13.1), tensor(8.1), tensor(9.), tensor(5.), tensor(11.1), tensor(9.), tensor(5007.), tensor(14.1), tensor(6.1), tensor(5001.), tensor(5008.), tensor(18.2), tensor(4.2), tensor(8.2), tensor(5001.), tensor(12.), tensor(9.2), tensor(17.1), tensor(6.2), tensor(11.2), tensor(9.1), tensor(13.), tensor(5008.), tensor(15.), tensor(5.1), tensor(6.), tensor(5.1), tensor(5004.), tensor(16.), tensor(17.), tensor(5002.), tensor(12.1), tensor(14.1), tensor(17.1), tensor(5010.), tensor(18.), tensor(12.), tensor(9.2), tensor(6.1), tensor(7.1), tensor(15.1), tensor(8.1), tensor(5006.), tensor(5010.), tensor(14.), tensor(19.), tensor(5003.), tensor(13.), tensor(18.1), tensor(12.1), tensor(10.), tensor(12.), tensor(16.2), tensor(16.), tensor(15.1), tensor(3.), tensor(3.2), tensor(8.), tensor(5007.), tensor(15.), tensor(0.), tensor(8.), tensor(5004.), tensor(13.1), tensor(7.1), tensor(19.1), tensor(4.), tensor(18.2), tensor(1.), tensor(13.), tensor(11.)}
unique_values_sorted: tensor([0.0e+00, 1.0e+00, 2.0e+00, 3.0e+00, 3.1e+00, 3.2e+00, 4.0e+00, 4.1e+00,
        4.2e+00, 5.0e+00, 5.1e+00, 6.0e+00, 6.1e+00, 6.2e+00, 7.0e+00, 7.1e+00,
        8.0e+00, 8.1e+00, 8.2e+00, 9.0e+00, 9.1e+00, 9.2e+00, 1.0e+01, 1.1e+01,
        1.1e+01, 1.1e+01, 1.2e+01, 1.2e+01, 1.3e+01, 1.3e+01, 1.3e+01, 1.4e+01,
        1.4e+01, 1.5e+01, 1.5e+01, 1.6e+01, 1.6e+01, 1.6e+01, 1.7e+01, 1.7e+01,
        1.8e+01, 1.8e+01, 1.8e+01, 1.9e+01, 1.9e+01, 5.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 5.0e+03,
        5.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 5.0e+03, 5.0e+03])


The problem is only one of the printing format, not of the data format of your tensors. Something triggers your tensors to be printed in what is sometimes called scientific notation or E notation.
You can manually turn off printing in scientific notation via torch.set_printoptions():
import torch

t = torch.tensor([0.0, 1.0, 5000])

print(t)
# >>> tensor([0.0000e+00, 1.0000e+00, 5.0000e+03])

torch.set_printoptions(sci_mode=False)  # Disable scientific notation for printing

print(t)
# >>> tensor([        0.,         1.,      5000.])

Note that this is a global change, i.e. all future printouts of tensors during
the runtime of your program will be affected. Of course, you can set new print options at any time by another call of torch.set_printoptions().
